# Setar valor de campo Select dinamicamente em formulário reativo Angular

Tags: angular, formulário, html-select

Tenho o seguinte campo select:

***.html***

```
<div class="col-md-4">
     <div class="mda-form-group">
          <select class="mda-form-control" formControlName="state"
           (change)="getCities($event.target.value)"aria-placeholder="Select a State...">
               <option value="">--Selecione um valor--</option>
               <option *ngFor="let state of valuesState" [value]="state.stateId">{{state.name}}</option>
          </select>
          <label>Estado</label>
      </div>
</div>
```

toda vez que um estado é selecionado o select da cidade é atualizado.
O problema é que coloquei uma função para buscar Cep e atualizar os campos automaticamente.

***.component.ts***

```
  zipQuery() {
    let zipCode = this.valForm.get('address.zipCode').value
    //Nova variável "cep" somente com dígitos.
    var zip = zipCode.replace(/\D/g, '');
    if (zip != "") {
      var validateZip = /^[0-9]{8}$/;
      //Valida o formato do CEP.
      if (validateZip.test(zip)) {
        this.ZipCodeService.getZipCode(zip).subscribe(res => {
          this.data = res;
          this.resetAddressForm();
          this.populateDataForm(this.data);
        })
      }
    }
  }

  resetAddressForm() {
    this.valForm.patchValue({
      address: {
        addressName: null,
        number: null,
        complement: null,
        neighborhood: null,
        state: null
      }
    })
  }

  populateDataForm(data) {
    this.stateService.getStateUf(data.uf).subscribe((states: States[]) => {
      this.valuesState = states;
      console.log(this.valuesState);
    });
    this.valForm.patchValue({
      address: {
        addressName: data.logradouro,
        neighborhood: data.bairro,
        zipCode: data.cep,
        state: this.valuesState
      }
    });
```

Estou recebendo o seguinte erro:

```
:4200/vendor.js:68903 ERROR Error: Error trying to diff 'Minas Gerais'. Only arrays and iterables are allowed
    at DefaultIterableDiffer.diff (:4200/vendor.js:89095)
    at NgForOf.ngDoCheck (:4200/vendor.js:30297)
    at callHook (:4200/vendor.js:67357)
    at callHooks (:4200/vendor.js:67317)
    at executeCheckHooks (:4200/vendor.js:67239)
    at selectIndexInternal (:4200/vendor.js:72036)
    at ɵɵadvance (:4200/vendor.js:72004)
    at CreateCustomersComponent_Template (ng:///CreateCustomersComponent.js:363)
    at executeTemplate (:4200/vendor.js:74125)
    at refreshView (:4200/vendor.js:73972)
```

E além disso, mesmo que eu consiga resolver o problema e popular essas informações, como faço para deixar o valor selecionado?

Grato,

Comment: me parece que o valuesState ta sendo usado como valor do select e tambem como as opçoões o certo é ter um array de estados

Comment: Obrigado Eduardo! Tinha esse problema também, mas o problema maior era em uma chamada assíncrona, que estava retornando o valor depois da linha de comando.